# Why is apache2 still in my ubuntu after I have deleted?

Tags: apt, server, apache2, nginx

So, I wanted to learn how to use the Nginx web server, and I wanted to try it out in my local machine, but I had apache2 installed in my laptop (ubuntu 20.04 LTS), so I tried to remove it using the following command:

1. I have stop apache2 from running using: `sudo service apache2 stop`
2. Then I removed and cleaned up all the apache2 packages with: `sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2-bin apache2.2-common`
3. Finally, just in case any clean up is needed I ran: `sudo apt-get autoremove`

But when I go back to my browser (Chrome), and type localhost I get the default homepage for apache2.

[image: DefaultWepPageApache2]

How can I remove it completely? I want this because I want to use the Nginx web server. I am learning about web architecture so excuse my question is not well-formatted.

Comment: Chrome will often cache things for a while. Are you certain it's not just the cached version of the page that's being loaded? Also, I do not believe the `/var/www` directory is removed when Apache is taken out so, if you have nginx or another web server installed, that may be serving the page 

Comment: Run `sudo ss -ltpn | grep :80` to see the process listening the _http_ port.

Comment: Check the settings in Chrome. I think it is set as the first page it opens. And like @matigo wrote it is cached.

Comment: @FedKad `users:(("nginx",pid=55760,fd=6),("nginx",pid=55759,fd=6),("nginx",pid=55758,fd=6),("nginx",pid=55757,fd=6),("nginx",pid=55756,fd=6))`, i got this when I ran the command

Comment: @matigo I don't know, how can I check that it is a cached version of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to FedKad, your machine is already running Nginx. Both Apache and Nginx use the `/var/www/html` directory as their default starting point.

When you uninstall Apache, the files contained within that default directory are not deleted as that may delete a bunch of your work. For this reason, the default Apache file, `index.html` was left intact. When you visit http://localhost in your browser, Nginx is serving the `index.html` that came with Apache, nothing more.

You can confirm this by checking your Nginx logs located in `/var/log/nginx`.